# MySQL crash -> innodb recovery not working -> trying another way

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb, recovery

Good day to you.

I used my MySQL server with "innodb_file_per_table" option, and now server is crashed. I want to recover this server using this way:

- Uninstall old MySQL
- Install new MySQL
- Add "innodb_file_per_table" in MySQL configuration
- Copy databases folders (only my, not mysql) from old MySQL/data to new MySQL/data

In every folder I have two files, .frm and .ibd, and looks like this files have all data from my databases tables.

But, after copying, tables in this databases didn't work: when I try to open some table, I get error: Table xxx doesn't exist in engine.

I tried REPAIR command, but it isn't helpful.

If you know how to finish my way of repair — please help.

...I know that I need to copy ibdata1 also, but it looks so dead for recovery, so I try way that I try.

Answer (score 0):

REPAIR command won't help with InnoDB.

If you're lucky enough the best you can do is:
1. Start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery=4 (try 5, 6 values if InnoDB fails to start). Make sure innodb_purge_threads=0.
2. Dump the database with mysqldump tool. Yes, it may be slow, but there is no other choice.
3. Create new empty InnoDB table space and reload the dump.

If MySQL fails to start with innodb_force_recovery=6, then recovery from backups is the only option. Well, you can fetch records from *.ibd files, but this is tedious job - google data recovery tool from percona

**UPDATE**: Data recovery toolkit moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy everything, not only the data folder
For example, without the ibdata file, mysql don't know where the tables are stored.

https://serverfault.com/questions/487159/what-is-the-ibdata1-file-in-my-var-lib-mysql-directory